# BibLaTeX: Custom citation command for softwares

Tags: biblatex, citing

I'm trying to do a custom `\citesoftware` command for BibLaTeX. I would like to cite in the document a software like

```
NameOfTheSoftware, Developers Year
```

For instance, for the entry

```
@software{hadoop,
  author = {{Apache Software Foundation}},
  title = {Hadoop},
  url = {https://hadoop.apache.org},
  version = {0.20.2},
  date = {2010-02-19},
}
```

I would like to have

```
Hadoop, Apache Software Fundation 2010
```

For now I have something like this:

```
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=numeric,
            doi=false,
            isbn=false,
            url=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{software.bib}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citesoftware}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\ifentrytype{software}{
    \printfield{title}%
    \setunit{\space}%
    \printfield{author}%
    \setunit{\space}%
    \printfield{year}}{\GenericError{}{Not a software entry}{}{}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```

Unfortunately, I do not know why, on the output file I only got title and year, but no "authors".

```
Hadoop, 2016
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Directly from the package documentation:

> The biblatex package implements three distinct data types to handle
>   bibliographic data: name lists, literal lists, and fields.

The data type `author` is of the kind *list (name)*, hence you have to use `\printnames{author}` instead of `\printfield{author}`:

```
\begin{filecontents}{software.bib}
    @software{hadoop,
        author = {{Apache Software Foundation}},
        title = {Hadoop},
        url = {https://hadoop.apache.org},
        version = {0.20.2},
        date = {2010-02-19},
        }
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=numeric,backend=biber,
    doi=false,
    isbn=false,
    url=false]{biblatex}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citesoftware}
    {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
        \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
        \usebibmacro{prenote}}
    {\ifentrytype{software}{% this % is necessary in order avoiding undesidered space
            \printfield{title}%
            \setunit{\addcomma\addspace}% , added
            \printnames{author}%
            \setunit{\addspace}%
            \printfield{year}}{\GenericError{}{Not a software entry}{}{}}}
    {\multicitedelim}
    {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\addbibresource{software.bib}

\begin{document}

    This is the big data citation: \citesoftware{hadoop}

    \printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]